# Header element set to inline expands outside of container div

Tags: html, css, css-float

*Coding simple php/html/css site based on the CSS grid system at www.cssgrid.net*

I have set my headers to `display: inline` to be able to print `back to top´ links on the **same line** as my section headers. Like this:

```
<h2 id="section1">Section 1</h2>
<a href="#top" class="scroll small">Back to top</a>
```

This renders as follows *(Stackoverflow doesn't support this, so imagine the bold text being a header)*

> **Section 1** *Back to top*

This is **all fine** and dandy and just as I want, the problem comes on **other places** where I use headers, for example in the following context. *(Please note that this is not a question weather or not to use CSS grid templates, but a question about headers. So please refrain from any comments about the general structure)*.

```
<div class="container" id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="eightcol" id="first-div">
            <h1>This is a header</h1>
            <p>This is a p-tag</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fourcol last" id="second-div">
            <div id="twitter">
                <p>Twitter here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This does not render *right*, at least not according to **what I want**. This renders as the following mockup shows:

```
main
--------------------------
| first-div | second-div |
| This is a header       |
| This is a | Twitter    |
| p-tag     | here       |
--------------------------
```

Perhaps not the most artistic ascii-render, but the point is that **the header expands** into the area of the div floated next to it.

What should I do to make it wrap in its **containing div**?

**Edit:**
*I've created a fiddle with the code, the error does not occur there though. No idea what's going on. http://jsfiddle.net/nefGZ/*

Comment: post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Trying, currently I'm trying to make the error actually occur there, it doesn't at the moment.

Comment: Original question edited with link to fiddle. It works in the fiddle though...

Comment: @InfiniteSquirrel: Post the page itself then

Comment: @prash Do some research. I've posted very few questions, and some of them has not gotten acceptable answers. Edit: And perhaps check out The Summer of Love http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/?cb=1 :)

Comment: I just reminded you,its ok fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've found the problem.

If you inspect the header on Chrome (Edit as HTML), this is what you'll get:

```
<h1>HEJ&nbsp;och&nbsp;välkommen&nbsp;till&nbsp;Basårsmottagningens&nbsp;hemsida!</h1>
```

It's all those `&nbsp;` that's preventing the word wrap.

*Edit by question author: Always check your copy pasted text, especially when pasting from PDF or Word.*

Comment: Oh for crying out loud, I believed I fixed all those stupid erorrs. They occurred from copy-pasting text from a pdf. I corrected them (rewrote the damn thing), but i obviously missed the header. **Thanks**!

Answer (score 0):

put a

> display: inline-block

style on the H1, and I think you will be fine